# My Minecraft Forge wont work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

I have forge 1.7.2 and every time i try to launch Minecraft it just brings me back to the Minecraft launcher instead of launching the game

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: No, it just sends me back to the launcher

Comment: We need a bit more detail.

Comment: well when i go to development console I noticed that it said

Comment: ignoring visibility rule and showing launcher due to a game crash

Comment: @TreasureHun7er5 this happens when you install forge incorrectly, I know exactly what you mean as I've had this happen myself. Follow the direction in the answer below to fix your problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's modded Minecraft tech support.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you delete your .minecraft folder (find this by typing `%appdata%` in the Start menu search) then follow the following steps:

1. Launch Minecraft using the launcher.
2. Make a new profile and edit it to launch in the version of Forge you have downloaded.
3. Launch that profile and wait until it reaches the main menu then close it.
4. Run the Forge installer (you would have got it from the Forge website).
5. Oonce forge is downloaded it will give you a message "successfully installed Forge".
6. Select profile "Forge"
7. Run game!

Answer (score -4):

Try seeing if you have the right version of forge that you downloaded, because if you don't, it might not work.